# calculation in list of dictionaries based on assigning the values for its keys in another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, hashmap

How to calculate in list of dictionaries based on assigning the values for its keys in another dictionary?

How to do this for the following input, print in descending order of `bid` based on summation of value of `itype` in `coef`

```
class ininput(NamedTuple):
    itype: str  
    bid: int 
    
coefficient= {'dr e': 2.0,'ph': 1.0,'c-in': 0.8,'bk': 0.25}
    
def calvalue(ininputs: Iterable[ininput]) -> List[int]:pass
    outf=[]
    v=sorted(ininputs, key='bid')
    for ininput in ininputs:
        for i in v:
            if ininput.bid==i:
                x=ininput.itype
                outf.append(sum(coefficient[x]))
    outf=sorted(outf,reverse=True)
    return outf

def main():
   ininput=[{"itype":"ph","bid":1},{"itype":"bk","bid":2},{"itype":"c_in","bid":3},{"itype":"dr e","bid":4},{"itype":"c_in","bid":4}]
    sortbid = calvalue(ininputs)
    for bid in sortbid:
        print(bid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample input:

```
coefficient= {'dr e': 2.0,'ph': 1.0,'c-in': 0.8,'bk': 0.25}
ininput=[{"itype":"ph:,"bid":1},{"itype":"bk","bid":2},{"itype":"c_in","bid":3},{"itype":"dr e","bid":4},{"itype":"c_in","bid":4}]
```

In order to calculate output:
**calculation for given input** is based on **coefficient** values, therefore for each `bid` we should calculate:

For `bid`=1=> `itype`= `ph`, the `coefficient` of `ph` is `1`

For `bid`=2=> `itype`= `bk`, the `coefficient` of `bk` is `0.25`

For `bid`=3=> `itype`= `c-in`, the `coefficient` of `c-in` is `0.8`

For `bid`=4=> `itype`= `c-in` && `itype`= `dr e` , the `coefficient` of them are `2 (dr e)+0.8 (c_in)=2.8`

**Sample Output**:(based on above calculation)
Then, sort the `bid` based on `descending order` of above calculation
`[4,1,3,2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fix typos like:

`c-in` in `coefficient` while `c_in` in `ininput`

`"itype":"ph:,"` -> `"itype": "ph"`

`sortbid = calvalue(ininputs)` -> `sortbid = calvalue(ininput)`

2.

```
coefficient= {'dr e': 2.0, 'ph': 1.0, 'c_in': 0.8, 'bk': 0.25}

def calvalue(ininputs):
    # initialize a sum dict with 0
    sum_dict = {_["bid"]: 0 for _ in ininputs}
    # add according to "itype"'s value
    for _ in ininputs:
        sum_dict[_["bid"]] += coefficient[_["itype"]]
    # sort and reverse
    sorted_bid = sorted(sum_dict, key=sum_dict.get)[::-1]
    return sorted_bid


def main():
    ininput = [
        {"itype": "ph", "bid": 1},
        {"itype": "bk", "bid": 2},
        {"itype": "c_in", "bid": 3},
        {"itype": "dr e", "bid": 4},
        {"itype": "c_in", "bid": 4}
    ]
    sortbid = calvalue(ininput)
    print(sortbid)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Outcome:

```
[4, 1, 3, 2]
```